# Append to PATH environment variable in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, path, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

How can I append or prepend a custom directory to the `PATH` environment variable in Eclipse CDT?

I am referring to the environment variables which can be specified at these locations:

- for the C/C++ build environment
- for C/C++ launch configurations
- for external tool launch configurations

The custom directory should be prepended or appended to the `PATH` environment variable used by Eclipse itself (referred to as "native environment").
Attempting to set it the usual way (`PATH=/my/custom/directory:${PATH}`) does not work for launch configurations.

Comment: At least in the launch configuration `PATH=/my/custom/directory:${env_var:PATH}` (with the option _Replace native environment with specified environment_) should work.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, that appears to work for launch configurations, regardless of whether the environment is appended or replaced. For the C/C++ build environment, `PATH=/my/custom/directory:${PATH}` seems to work. Feel free to make it an answer (bonus points for linking to the documentation of those predefined variables ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a **launch configuration** you can use the `env_var` variable with the argument `PATH`:

```
${env_var:PATH}
```

Since plug-ins can contribute variables (e.g. `git_branch` by EGit) there is no documentation with a list of all variables and their arguments. In the *New/Edit Environment Variable* dialog, if you click *Variables...* and select the `env_var` variable, there is the following description at the bottom of the dialog (in my view the [screenshot with `env_var` without arguments shown in the C/C++ Development User Guide is not correct here](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_env.htm)):

> Returns the value of an environment variable. An environment variable
>   name must be specified as an argument.

In the **C/C++ build environment**, I would assume this would work too. But you've already found out that **`${PATH}`** works here for sure.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to compose environment variable on this editor? For example, I've created DEV_DIR and then created a TARGET with this value ${env_var:DEV_DIR}/target. But this is not working.

Comment: @Cristiano `${env_var:DEV_DIR}/target` should work if `DEV_DIR` is an environment variable visible to Eclipse (check _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Configuration_, section `*** System environment variables:`).