# Python's shutil.wich('docker') sometimes return empty result

Tags: python, eclipse, docker

I am using Python 3.8.5, on Mac. Need to find location of the docker executable.
The following code

```
DOCKER_PATH = shutil.which('docker')
```

return empty result on my Mac when I run it from Eclipse.
If I open terminal, I do have docker installed

```
which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Also this work fine

```
python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Oct 22 2020, 19:13:38) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.which('docker')
'/usr/local/bin/docker'
>>>
```

Any ideas, what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse may not have `/usr/local/bin` defined in its `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use the same PATH as other applications? Is there way Eclipse will use the same PATH?

Comment: You may wish to verify by running Python code that will `import os` and then `print(os.environ['PATH'])`, along with `os.path.isfile('/usr/local/bin/docker')`.   I don't have access to your machines to do this for you.

Comment: hm...indeed print(os.environ['PATH']) returns /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin and os.path.isfile('/usr/local/bin/docker') return True. But then i am not sure where is the fault, either PATH is not passed to Eclipse or the way i use shutil.which('docker') is not the correct way to find location of docker executable

Comment: It's likely due to Eclipse started with a specific restricted set of environment variables defined - check the related startup scripts for Eclipse on your system, or see how Eclipse handles environment variables.

Comment: Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678675/append-to-path-environment-variable-in-eclipse)

Comment: You shouldn't need a `docker` binary in this context; can you use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead?  Also remember that you can pretty easily use Docker to take over the whole host; be extra careful with basic security concerns, and consider hard whether you _need_ Docker access, or whether you can use other techniques instead.