# Use System Environment variables in .project file

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-project-file

I have a demo C project where I have a linked resource file relative to a variable defined in the variableList section , **FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV**
The value of **FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV** I want to be updated dynamically from the environment.
I have tried to use **file:/$%7BFIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV%7D** or file:/%FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV% but with no success.

If the environment variable *FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV=C:/DEMO_LIBS* then my expectation is to have on the end the file **src/main.c** linked to **C:/DEMO_LIBS/src/main.c**

Here is the **.project** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>TestDemoProject</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder</name>
        <triggers>clean,full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder</name>
        <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>
</natures>
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>src/main.c</name>
        <type>1</type>
        <locationURI>FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV/src/main.c</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
<variableList>
    <variable>
        <name>FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV</name>
        <value>file:/%FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV%</value>
    </variable>
</variableList>
```

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I don't think there is any support for accessing environment variables anywhere in the .project.

Comment: or on the workspace level would be possible?

Comment: I would also guess that environment variables are not supported here. At places where environment variables are supported, e.g. in [launch configurations, the syntax is  `${env_var:FIRMWARE_DIR_FROM_ENV}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698254/6505250).